# Что такое события верхнего уровня?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При прочтении [статьи](https://medium.com/@kanby/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-react-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-3bc1f4e021f4), наткнулся на следующее

> React не назначает события на дочерние элементы сам. React будет слушать все события на верхнем уровне, используя простой слушатель событий. Это хорошо для производительности и также означает, что React не нужно беспокоиться об отслеживании при обновлении DOM.

Что такое события верхнего уровня? Какие еще бывают? Помогите разобраться с этим.

Comment: события документа

Comment: @Igor, т.е.  все события DOM - события верхнего уровня?

Comment: @Igor, Спасибо, внесли ясность. А какие события не являются событиями верхнего уровня тогда?
Оформите как ответ, я его приму.

Comment: не, я с реактом не работал, мог ошибиться. Не верхнего уровня - очевидно, выстреливающие для конкретных DOM элементов.

Comment: @PolarBear, все гораздо проще: у событий вообще нет такой характеристики как "уровень". В тексте речь об уровне не событий, а _обработчиков (слушателях, listener)_... если точнее - об уровне их владельцев. Владельцами являются узлы DOM - и вот _у них_, характеристика "уровень" (=уровень вложенности) как раз есть :]

Comment: @yar85, т.е. получается, реакт отслеживает события в компоненте на самом верхнем (по вложенности) для этого компонента узле DOM. И за счет этого получаем выигрыш в производительности. Теперь все встало на свои места. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да, именно так, если верить тексту статьи (сам я с реактом не настолько глубоко знаком, но данная техника назначения обработчиков часто используется теми, чей мозг еще не скушала jQuery  :D). Рад помочь :)